# Using .NET CLR in luajit as a module

Tags: c#, c, .net, lua, clr

I'm writing a C/C++ application which uses a luajit runtime. In this runtime I want to load .NET DLLs and call functions/create objects exposed by it.

After a lot of research I've found some libraries which can achieve this, luainterface for example. But the problem with all these libraries is that they require a Lua runtime running in .NET itself.

Is there a library which I can preferably `require` as a module from which I can use .NET DLLs?

Comment: You cannot embed .NET, it is not a library, it's a runtime. Your main process must be started as .NET, andd inside of it you can load your C/C++ and lua modules.

Comment: I know it's possible to start a .NET runtime in a DLL, so it is possible to expose the CLR functions through some wrapper.
I've actually started a project which does this but it's really hard so I'm curious if there already is a solution for this problem.

Comment: AFAIK, the best you can do is start .NET in a separate process and then interact with it via COM. I wouldn't name it "start a .NET runtime in a DLL" though.

Comment: It is definitely possible to start a .NET runtime from a native application (just search for it), but I am not aware of library that interops it with Lua in this way. Maybe LuaInterface can be tweaked to accept an existing Lua instance and be called externally.